# Android shows denial message though selinux policy for the same is available

Tags: android, android-source, selinux

For my appconf service, got a selinux policy already as below: (showing only required lines)

```
allow modeappconf system_data_file:dir search;
```

But throws below denial message:

```
W cat     : type=1400 audit(0.0:427): avc: denied { search } for name="data" dev="dm-10" ino=2949121 scontext=u:r:modeappconf:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:system_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
```

What further information is missing here ?